# Error: My query (containing subqueries) returns blank

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, subquery, ssms

```
 SELECT c.id,c.email,cs.Source
 FROM contact c INNER JOIN contactsource__C cs  ON cs.contactid__c = c.id
 WHERE cs.Source IN (SELECT cs.Source FROM contact c
 INNER JOIN contactsource__C cs ON cs.contactid__c = c.id
 WHERE cs.Source = 'DOGS')
 AND cs.Source IN (SELECT cs.Source FROM contact c
 INNER JOIN contactsource__C cs ON cs.contactid__c = c.id
 WHERE cs.Source = 'CATS')
```

I want a list of emails which has both 'DOGS' and 'CATS' as the Source.

The Source will be on seperate rows in table: contactsource, but with the same contact_id (which is PK id in table: contact)

I get no results when I run this (running subqueries individually does return results, and there are instances where source is both CATS and DOGS, noted on separate rows)

Comment: try to make select columns in subqueries and conditional columns to lower or upper

Comment: Why do you use subqueries at all? You can simply say `WHERE cs.Source IN ('DOGS', 'CATS')`, since that's all the subqueries can return.

Comment: Left justified SQL makes the code so much harder to read - and to correct.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Comment: Don't use the same alias names inside and outside the subqueries. As to why it's not working: A cs record has one source, it cannot match 'DOGS' and 'CATS' at the same time. It should hence not be the source you are looking for in the subqueries, but contact IDs.

Comment: By the way: always tag your DBMS (Oracle, MySQL, SQL Server PostgreSQL, ...) when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 1):

> > I want a list of emails which has both 'DOGS' and 'CATS' as the Source.

So select from `contact` only and put the criteria in the WHERE clause:

```
select id, email
from contact
where id in
(
  select contactid__c
  from contactsource__C
  where source in ('DOGS', 'CATS')
  group by contactid__c
  having count(distinct source) = 2
);
```

Comment: How will you find  'id' from the subquery (contactid_c) without a JOIN?

Comment: As you see I aggregate per contact ID (`GROUP BY` clause). So I get one record per contact ID. I only select dogs and cats and in the `HAVING` clause I say I only want to keep contact IDs that have two different sources, i.e. both cats and dogs.

Answer (score 0):

Making all the coditional columns to lower or upper may work.

```
 SELECT c.id,c.email,cs.Source
 FROM contact c INNER JOIN contactsource__C cs  ON cs.contactid__c = c.id
 WHERE lower(cs.Source) IN (SELECT lower(cs.Source) FROM contact c
 INNER JOIN contactsource__C cs ON cs.contactid__c = c.id
 WHERE cs.Source = 'DOGS')
 AND lower(cs.Source) IN (SELECT lower(cs.Source) FROM contact c
 INNER JOIN contactsource__C cs ON cs.contactid__c = c.id
 WHERE cs.Source = 'CATS')
```

Answer (score 0):

First you got two identical subqueries, so it's better to join them together by just changing the predicate in the subquery, which becomes:

```
SELECT
   cs.Source
FROM contact c
INNER JOIN contactsource__C cs
   ON cs.contactid__c = c.id
WHERE cs.Source = 'DOGS' or cs.Source = 'CATS';
```

But I don't know what you are expecting the subquery to produce, other than the results 'CATS' or 'DOGS', because you're trying to select the same column that you put in the condition clause:

```
select 
   u.username 
from dba_users u 
inner join dba_profiles p
   on u.profile = p.profile 
where u.username = 'SYS';

USERNAME
-----------------------------------------------
SYS
SYS
SYS
SYS
SYS
SYS
SYS
SYS
SYS
SYS
SYS
SYS
```

Therefore the result from your subquery will be either 'CATS' or 'DOGS'.

So your query should be something like this:

```
SELECT
   c.id,
   c.email,
   cs.Source
FROM contact c
INNER JOIN contactsource__C cs
   ON cs.contactid__c = c.id
WHERE cs.Source = 'DOGS' OR cs.Source='CATS';
```

Comment: Won't this return all instances of 'id' where Source is DOGS or CATS, and not both?

Comment: The "OR" here means that the Source could be 'DOGS' or could be 'CATS' so that mean both of them, when you write 'AND', this indicates that the both sides of the "WHERE" clause should be true at the same time and you can't have the same result of the same column at the same exact time.

Comment: example:

SQL> select username from dba_users where username = 'SYS' AND username = 'HR';

no rows selected


SQL> select username from dba_users where username = 'SYS' OR username = 'HR';

USERNAME
-------------------
SYS
HR